# Can I use fire base to host my flutter web app while still using AWS amplify for Cognito and DataStore

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-amplify, flutter-web, amplify-flutter

Hi I was wondering if it was possible to host my flutter Web app on Firebase while using AWS Amplify for its DataStore and Cognito services or does AWS NOT support Flutter Web at all yet. Im having issues hosting it on Amplify and was wondering if there were any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

After you build it, a Flutter web app is just a bunch of HTML and JavaScript, so you can serve it from any hosting platform. And once the JavaScript runs in the browser, it can connect to any service.

If you're having trouble making something work, we can typically help better if you show us the [minimal information that is needed to reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).